# PHP get URI parts of URL

Tags: php, uri

I have 2 strings and substitute them, so I get just URI parts.

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost/project/';
$url      = 'http://localhost/project/controller/action/param1/param2';
```

I am checking for URI parts.

```
$only_segments = str_replace($base_url, '', $real_url);
```

Basicly I do: `{url} - {base_url} = {only_segments}`

Then I can get segments:

```
$parts = explode('/', $only_segments);
print_r($parts);
```

**Question:**

Am I on right path or can it be done easier with **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** ?

*Note: I don't want `project` in URI parts, it is sub-folder of localhost.*

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php will make your life easier

Comment: You could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`: http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look into [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). That will get you most of the way there. All you would need to do is remove the portion of the path that is part of your base URL.

```
print_r(parse_url('http://localhost/project/controller/action/param1/param2'));

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => localhost
    [path] => /project/controller/action/param1/param2
)
```

Comment: "remove base_url" that is core of my question. Should I use `str_replace` or `substr`? I can do this many ways, looking for easiest one.

Comment: It should be said if there's a query string: `'http://localhost/project/controller/action/param1/param2?foo=bar'` then it will be placed in in the array as well with the array key `query` like so: `'query' => 'foo=bar'`

Answer (score 5):

A more complete Example:

```
var_dump(parse_url(http://lambo-car-dealer.com/Lambo/All+Models/2018/?limits=10&advance_options=no));
```

output:

```
array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(48) "lambo-car-dealer.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(44) "/Lambo/All+Models/2018/"
 ["query"]=>
 string(121) "limits=10&advance_options=no"
```

}

Also can get it this way:

```
$URL = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$URI = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```