# preg_match take last 15 digit or last / "Slash"

Tags: php, url, match, preg-match

hello i am working about something to attach facebook with my webiste

how can i with preg_match take last 15 digit or last /"Slash" i tried with

```
$slashess = explode("/", $result[1]); 
$idofpost = $slashess[5];
```

but this sometime when is diffrent is taking wrong one of this link example:

example:

```
`https://www.facebook.com/OXLMultimediaAmritsar/photos/a.799432256809419.1073741854.459335454152436/799432413476070`
```

or `https://www.facebook.com/799432413476070`

```
preg_match('/ somethinghere /' ,$url);
```

--> has to be with preg_match <--

Comment: Tempted to close with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956180/php-get-uri-parts-of-url

Comment: `end($slashess)` returns the last element of `$slashess`.

Comment: Or just use `basename()`..

Comment: _Why_ does it have to be with `preg_match()`? Is this for an assignment requiring you use a regular expression?

Comment: Please don't change completly your question!

Comment: If you have a new question ask a new one!

Comment: i cannot ask new one so i am need to change this one

Comment: @moderator: what do you think about that?

Comment: @Toto i am not happy to do this but i have to do this

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) or [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) as pointed out in the comments and you must use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get the last 15 digits at the end of the string after the last forward slash, you might use:

[`/\K\d{15}$`](https://regex101.com/r/G61ArC/1)

- `\K` Reset the startingpoint of the reported match
- `\d{15}` Match 15 digits
- `$` The end of the string

[Demo php preg_match](https://3v4l.org/35jE5)

[Demo php end and basename](https://3v4l.org/iBkaM)