# How to retrieve value from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

What i wanted to do is that i wanted to get data from the URL , but i met some problem which it take the wrong value

Here is an example of the that i have

```
 localhost/index.php/registerform/3/4/5
```

> What I Tried: echo $id[3]; 
>       The result of the code is : "a"

What i wanted:

Get String From URL , i wanted to retrieve "3" and set it as $id

```
the code $id[3] won't work
```

How should i do that ?

---

And other question is that is that possible to set

```
 localhost/index.php/registerform/3/4/5
```

into array ?
localhost as [0],index.php as [1] and so on .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get URI parts of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956180/php-get-uri-parts-of-url)

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180115/how-to-get-id-from-url-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `segment_array()` from URI library

> use below code in your controller

```
echo var_dump($this->uri->segment_array());die;
```

> it will give you controller/Method/3/4/5 as array and from array you can assign each array element in variable

```
Array
(
    [1] => Contoller Name
    [2] => Method Name
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the function you can get variables from URL like this

```
 public function function_name($v1, $v2, $v3){
    echo 'Variable one '.$v1.' Variable two '.$v2.' Variable three '.$v3;
 }
```

OR

```
public function function_name($v1, $v2, $v3){
    echo 'Variable one '.$this->uri->segment(3).' Variable two '.$this->uri->segment(4).' Variable three '.$this->uri->segment(5);
 }
```