# How to extract a specific parameter in a URL?

Tags: php

I'm trying to only strip out a specific parameter from a URL, but I can only do it at its base form. If the script I use adds additional parameter, then that messes up my output. Here is what I currently have

```
$str = str_replace("https://www.example.com/page/?id[]=", "","$baseUrl");
```

This works perfectly if the $baseUrl = [https://www.example.com/page/?id[]=](https://www.example.com/page/?id%5B%5D=)

However, the $baseURL can equal anything. A few examples are

```
https://www.example.com/page/?id[]=theid&size=50gb&date=11-15
https://www.example.com/page/?size=20gb&id[]=theid&os=windows10
https://www.example.com/page/?type=software&id[]=theid&size=50gb
https://www.example.com/page/?cost=1000&size=50gb&type=software&id[]=theid
```

How can I extract the value in just "id[]=" ?

Comment: You mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956180/php-get-uri-parts-of-url

Comment: This is http basics - `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobal arrays.

Comment: @u_mulder Think the URL is a string.

Comment: Hm, then it should be parsed as @NigelRen suggests.

Comment: You could do it with a regex `[&?]id(\[\])?=\K[^&]+` https://regex101.com/r/XAOsoF/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

// Inintialize URL to the variable 
$url = 'http://www.change.org/register?name[]=Joe&email=joe2020@gmail.com'; 
    
$url_components = parse_url($url); 

parse_str($url_components['query'], $params); 

echo ' Hi '.$params['name'][0].' your emailID is '.$params['email']; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.

```
preg_match('/\bid\[\]=([^&]+)/', $baseUrl, $id);
```

`$id[0]` will capture the entire match, while `$id[1]` will be just the ID value, i.e.

```
array(
    [0] => id[]=foo,
    [1] => foo
)
```